# Multiple beforeunload handlers in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, onbeforeunload

I am writing JavaScript for a plugin that will be used on clients' sites, and need to use a `beforeunload` handler to store some information to the user's cookies or localstorage for tracking purposes.

However, since I don't control the clients' sites, I'm concerned about the scenario where the client's page has already defined a beforeunload handler before we set ours. In particular, I'm worried about the case where the client's JavaScript creates a 'beforeunload' handler that returns a string to create an `'Are you sure you want to leave this page?'`-style popup, and the possibility that adding our handler after that may destroy or otherwise interfere with this functionality.

Based upon a little experimentation in the console in Chromium, ***it seems that if I add handlers using `jQuery(window).on('beforeunload', handler)`, then all the handlers get executed in the order they were added and then the existence and content of any confirmation dialog is determined solely by the final non-`undefined` return value***. So if the last handler added with an explicit return returns `null`, no message is shown, and if it returns a string, then a confirmation dialog with that string as its content is shown. This is the behaviour I want; it means that as long as I return `undefined` from the `beforeunload` handler that *I* add, I shouldn't break any of our clients' code.

***Can I rely upon this behaviour across all browsers, though? How about if the client added their original `beforeunload` handler via a mechanism other than jQuery, like explicitly assigning to `window.onbeforeunload` or using `window.addEventListener`?*** How is jQuery handling the assignment of multiple handlers behind the scenes?

Comment: `if (window.onbeforeunload) { oldBeforeUnload=onbeforeunload; onbeforeunload=function() { yourstuff(); oldBeforeUnload() }`

Comment: @mplungjan Well, firstly, that'd need to be `return oldBeforeUnload()`, not just `oldBeforeUnload()`, or you're breaking existing functionality. Secondly, I don't know whether this approach is necessary or whether adding the handlers using jQuery already behaves in something like this way - hence the question. I also don't know whether, if the client is using jQuery, your approach will break their ability to remove a handler using the jQuery `.off` method - I suspect it does.

Comment: It was just to give an idea. You may need to do both

Comment: You should just document that you add stuff to `onbeforeunload` and the clients that use your library should take care of it if he has events of his own to add. I promises you that you can't think of all the ways the client will abuse your library or the DOM :)

Comment: @TheBrain Sure, I can't handle every case, but my concern is that I might inadvertently blow stuff up even in the case where the client is adding beforeunload handlers in a standard, sensible way.

Answer (score 0):

what if you do it like this

```
 var x = window.onbeforeunload
 window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
       // do your stuf
       if (x) return x();
 }
```

so this way you'll return whatever the initial event handler was suppose to return.